# CSS Background-Blend-Mode over two Elements

Tags: css, gradient, background-blend-mode

Lets assume I have a *div* with a Gradient applied as a *background*-property.
I now want to overlay a black PNG (of smaller size) and set the PNG to have a *background-blend-mode* of overlay. Unfortunately I have no idea on how to achieve this.

I know I can have a working *background-blend-mode* when I render the Gradient into the CSS of the Div with the PNG image like:

```
background: url(../img/plus.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, #24cae4 0%, #1f81e3 100%);
background-blend-mode: overlay;
```

This however results in the Gradient being as small as the actual PNG, which is not a desired effect, like this:
[image]

What I want to achieve is this with pure CSS (if possible):

[image: Overlay PNG on top of a div with CSS-rendered Gradient]

Here a Codepen to illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxOXGP
Notice the Black Icon. I wanna overlay this.

Comment: could you provide a sample of how you have your html set up. maybe a jsfiddle too?

Comment: codepen added. It's a real simple setup.

Comment: Sorry, I must not be the right guy for this question, It seems to me that your codepen is doing exactly what you're looking for. I upvoted this question tho.

Comment: Thank you. I want the PNG to not be Black, I want it to be blended with the Background. I have updated the images to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `mix-blend-mode` instead of `background-blend-mode` and switch to simple text for the plus-sign or a webfont for more custom figures.

[Example Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwPYWa) of the below:

```css
.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ff0000, #0000ff);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff0000, #0000ff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff0000, #0000ff);
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 120px;
}
.center span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder">
  <div class="center"><span>+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1! Please include the snippet in the question for your answers. I added the snippet for you this time and it illustrates your solution nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

## The gradient sandwich

### Ingredients

- The `:before` forms the bottom z-layer with `z-index: 1`, it is full opacity
- The `.content` div forms the filling, central z-layer, with `z-index: 2`. It needs `position: relative` to take its z-index.
- The `:after` forms the top z-layer with `z-index: 3` and completes our lunch item. It is half opacity.

This is the tasty result:

[image: Sandwich result]

### Full Example

I have removed all but the standard CSS3 gradient for simplicity. View in a supporting browser.

```css
.gradient {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.gradient:before,
.gradient:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;  
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #24cae4 0%, #1f81e3 100%);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.gradient:before {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gradient:after {
  z-index: 3;
}
.overlayed_image {
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/9029.png);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <div class="content">
    You can see me! 
    <div class="overlayed_image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is a very nifty solution, it isn't quite what I am looking for since we basically overlay the PNG with Opacity but no Blending Options. The answer above yours demonstrates what I actually wanted to achieve. Thank you regardlessly (:

Comment: Oh, ok! No sandwich for you then :) I see what you needed now. Enjoy!